# kobuki don't go straight, get a little to the right in gazebo

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am learning about the kobuki robot simulator. I followed the instructions here http://wiki.ros.org/kobuki/Tutorials/Gazebo%20Simulation
when i control kobuki go straight, althought kobuki go straight but kobuki always get a little to the right. Why?
I am newbie, please explain it to me, thank you very much !
i use ubuntu 14.04 ros indigo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/338481/kobuki-don%27t-go-straight,-get-a-little-to-the-right-in-gazebo/) by [haitm](https://answers.ros.org/users/33064/haitm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-11-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I fixed it. I edited file kobuki.urdf.xacro. In here, I discovered: radius of left wheel and radius of right wheel is different. OMG. Simple error but I searched it all day. Standard code is also sometimes incorrect. :v

---

Originally posted by [haitm](https://answers.ros.org/users/33064/haitm/) with karma: 16 on 2019-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-25**:
I got curious: [yujinrobot/kobuki#400](https://github.com/yujinrobot/kobuki/issues/400).

Not expecting a response soon though.

**Comment by [haitm](https://answers.ros.org/users/33064/haitm/) on 2019-11-25**:
maybe..um..I think the author is a bit confused.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-26**:
Seems it will be fixed in [yujinrobot/kobuki#401](https://github.com/yujinrobot/kobuki/pull/401).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-28**:
This has been fixed in [yujinrobot/kobuki#401](https://github.com/yujinrobot/kobuki/pull/401).

You shouldn't need to edit any local files any more.